# Add class to all img if they have a certain ACF field

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields, attachments

I have an ACF field for image attachments so the user can choose 'rounded border' or 'square border'. How can I apply a class to all images depending on the value of that ACF field?

I can do it if the image is hardcoded into the template, but when it's part of a WYSIWYG editor I don't know how to target it and get the attachment meta data.

Here's how I do it on hardcoded images:

```
<?php
$attachments = get_sub_field('images');
foreach($attachments as $attachment){
  $corners = get_field('rounded_corners', $attachment['ID']);
?>
<img class="<?php echo $corners; ?>">
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Does anyone know how I can apply something similar to any WYSIWYG images?

I found the following from another answer, but I'm not sure how to query the ACF field...

```
function add_responsive_class($content)
{
    $content = mb_convert_encoding($content, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8");
    if (!empty($content)) {
        $document = new DOMDocument();
        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
        $document->loadHTML(utf8_decode($content));

        $imgs = $document->getElementsByTagName('img');
        foreach ($imgs as $img) {
          /* I'd want something here to look for $img['ID'] and then the ACF... */
          $img->setAttribute('class', 'img-fluid');
        }

        $html = $document->saveHTML();
        return $html;
    }
}
add_filter('the_content', 'add_responsive_class');
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you asked ACF?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.